# Eliminar todos los caracteres especiales a excepcion de algunos

Tags: java

Tengo un campo (input) Reply To para ingresar un eamil y luego enviar un mensaje. El problema es que modificando el código del front puedo hacer este input de tipo "text" e insertar caracteres especiales, que, al ser procesador por el servidor, arroja un error 500.

Conozco del metodo replaceAll, el tema es que no se como añadir caracteres para que sean ignorados. Esto es lo que tengo

```
replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

Y por lo que he leído en sitios como [***este***](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/remove-non-alphanumeric-characters-java-string) elimina todos los caracteres especiales a excepción de letras y números. Necesitaría añadir a esa lista de excepción el arroba (**@**) y el punto(**.**)

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Esto puede ayudarle: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40729568/8933039

Comment: Gracias. De todos modos encontre esto y es justo lo que buscaba https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624581/what-is-the-best-java-email-address-validation-method Salduos.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que lo que necesitas es validar el email, para eso java tiene su metodo establecido, que es bastante útil (Lo intuyo porque yo intente hacerlo asi tambien y las risas)

El método en cuestión es `isValidEmailAddress` el ya se encarga de limpiar el String que tienes que introducirle como parametro, si no existe tienes que capturar la excepción

```
public static boolean isValidEmailAddress(String email) {
 boolean result = true;
 try 
 {
   InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(email);
   emailAddr.validate();
 } 
 catch (AddressException ex) 
 {
    result = false;
 }
    return result;
 }
```

Y si no quieres usar los métodos que te proporciona java. Puedes usar un patrón estandarizado, el que te agrego a continuación

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Patrón para validar el email
    Pattern pattern = Pattern
            .compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                    + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");

    // El email a validar
    String email = "juanito@juanito.com";

    Matcher mather = pattern.matcher(email);

    if (mather.find() == true) {
        System.out.println("El email ingresado es válido.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("El email ingresado es inválido.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que tienes el email recibido desde un objeto llamado correo

```
final String email = validarString(correo.getEmail(), 100);
```

Yo utilizo el siguiente método para validar que si sea de tipo correo pero además que no exceda los 100 caracteres de longitud:

```
public String validarString(String campo, long longitud_maxima) {

    String filtro = campo;
    Pattern patron = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}");
    Matcher mat3 = patron.matcher(campo);

    if(mat3.matches()){
        //si el correo coincide, no haga nada, pero significa que pasó la validación
    }else{ //si el corrreo está mal escrito, devolvemos un null
    return null;
        } //fin validación email

        //validamos longitud mínima
        if (campo.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        //validamos si el usuario envía varios espacios en blanco
        int whitespace_counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < campo.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(campo.charAt(i))) {
                whitespace_counter++;
            }
        }

        if(campo.length() == whitespace_counter) {
            return null;
        }


    //validamos longitud máxima
    if(campo.length() > longitud_maxima) {
        return null;
    }
    return filtro;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opcion que nadie te menciono es el Api de Validaciones de Java (propuesto en el [JSR 303](https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/) como una de las librerias para [java-ee](/questions/tagged/java-ee)) que se integra de manera excelente (osea sin que tengas que llamarlo explicitamente como te yo voy a mostrar) con frameworks como [primefaces](/questions/tagged/primefaces), [richfaces](/questions/tagged/richfaces), [seam](/questions/tagged/seam) o [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) por dar unos ejemplos.

Para ello debes descargar [la dependencia](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api)

Si usas maven para ello podria quedar algo asi:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

El truco esta en poner tu validacion en una anotacion en tu bean

```
import javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;

public class User {

    @Min(value = 18, message = "Debe ser mayor de edad")
    @Max(value = 150, message = "La edad no puede ser mayor a 150")
    private int age;

    @Email(message = "revisa el correo")
    private String email;

    // setters y getters 
}
```

Y luego validiarlo, en nuestro caso con el codigo

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validador = factory.getValidator();

User usuario= new User();
usuario.setEmail("correo-invalido@invalido.");
usuario.setAge(16);

Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violaciones = validator.validate(usuario);
for (ConstraintViolation<User> violacion : violaciones) {
    System.out.println("Validacion no cumplida:" + violacion .getMessage());
}
```

La salida deberia de ser

> Validacion no cumplida: Debe ser mayor de edad
>
> Validacion no cumplida: revisa el correo

Las ventajas de esta solucion son:

- puedes modificar facilmente el codigo
- puedes agregar nuevas validaciones muy facilmente
- puedes personalizar la expresion regular para el correo ej. `@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9@\\.]+@midominio.com$", message = "Email be valid")`
- puedes obtener las validaciones antes de persistir gratis si usas alguno de los frameworks que mencione al inicio, incluso con enviar el mensaje de error al front si lo requieres